# How to tell if process is run by the Service Control Manager

Tags: windows-services

I have a few Windows Services written in C# that I have setup to support being run from the command line as a console app if a specific parameter is passed. Works great but I would love to be able to detect whether the app is being run by the service control mananger or from a command line.

Is there any way to tell at runtime if my app was started by the SCM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Environment.UserInteractive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx) will return false if the process is running under the SCM.

Comment: This works nicely as long as you do not enable the 'Allow service to interact with the desktop' option in the SCM. Not a problem for our services. Thanks Guardi!

Answer (score 1):

The SCM will call your OnStart method, so you could mark that event and make sure when you run from the command line, you don't call OnStart.  Or, you could check the startup parameters to see how the application was started.

Answer (score 0):

In C the function `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` will fail with `ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT`. This is the best way in C, wonder if C# exposes any of this?

> ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT
>
> This error is returned if the program is being run as a console application rather than as a service. If the program will be run as a console application for debugging purposes, structure it such that service-specific code is not called when this error is returned.